# RSense Vim plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

I'm new to Ruby and trying to set up my Vim <strike>as Ruby IDE</strike> to be more Ruby-friendly. Official Ruby's  website states that there is a special tool for this purpose - RSense. There used to be the original RSense here http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/ but now the website says not found. There is a supposedly "new" version of RSense on GitHub (https://github.com/rsense/rsense), but as I understood there is no Vim plugin for it...
Is there anyone who has set up RSense for Vim and how did you do it?

Comment: FWIW, Vim has never been, is not, will never be, and can't be an IDE.

Comment: Oh come on, don't be so picky on words. You know what I'm talking about. Of course it's NOT an IDE, but you can get Vim set up like a programming environment for a language to enable auto complete, syntax highlighting, etc. The original RSense was a "development tools for Vim, Emacs, etc"